# java custom event on event dispatch thread

Tags: java, events, event-dispatch-thread

I am building a java application and i have implemented custom listeners and events. The problem now is that there are many events and listeners and the application GUI thread is being blocked while the listeners process the events. Can this be solved using event dispatch thread? If so how?

The code for listeners:

```
public class ProjectChangeObserver
{
    private List<ProjectChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ProjectChangeListener>();

    public void addProjectChangeListener(ProjectChangeListener l)
    {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeProjectChangeListener(ProjectChangeListener l)
    {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    public void removeAllProjectChangeListeners()
    {
       listeners.clear();
    }

    public void fireProjectChange(ProjectChangeEvent e)
    {
      if(listeners.size() > 0)
       { 
          ArrayList<ProjectChangeListener> safeCopy = new ArrayList<ProjectChangeListener>(listeners);
          for (ProjectChangeListener cl : safeCopy ) {
              cl.onProjectChange(e);
        }
       } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the features of Swing is that it is [single-threaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).

However, there is nothing stopping you from spawning your own threads to do background processing. As long as you only make calls to `revalidate()` or `repaint()` then all the drawing will still be handled in the Swing thread.

(Remember that if you are going to be spawning other threads to do background work then ensure that your variables are declared `volatile` if you expect the Swing thread to see the same values as in your threads. Or pass the information back through another listener.)

If you are intending to do the painting itself (e.g. of custom components) in separate threads, then it is either not possible or very strongly discouraged depending on the situation. (Some exotic situations may permit multi-CPU generation of a scene in a custom thread-safe buffering class, but you're unlikely to be doing that).

If you are finding that your `Listener`s are CPU/network intensive, then you might want to think about the architecture of who is doing the majority of the shouting and who is doing the listening. I always try to minimise the amount of shouting in my "view" code so that it simply responds to events.

Incidentally, I've found [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) and its Beta sister [Lombok PG](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki) to greatly reduce the boilerplate of implementing the `Listener` pattern with [`@ListenerSupport`](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/%40ListenerSupport).

Comment: to be more precise im implementing a paste operation which just copys some elements to a vector (response to event), but the problem is if there are many elements it blocks the GUI thread. So if i understand your answer i should spawn a new thread and do the paste operation there?

Comment: Hmm, that's a tricky one because the user is generating an event and your view is responding to it.If you implement the processing in a separate thread and then fire a lightweight event (which the view can process quickly) then your users will be forced to experience a short delay. With my limited understanding of your project, I would actually suggest looking at speeding up the handling code of your view without getting caught up about threading.

Answer (score 1):

Quite to the contrary, this must be solved **avoiding** the Event Dispatch Thread ("GUI thread" is just another name for the same thing). You must use `SwingWorker` to start an asynchronous task in its own thread.

Comment: so if i understand correctly EDT should be used only for GUI and if i want custom events i need to fire the events in a new thread (and avoid the EDT)?

Comment: You can execute any code you like in the EDT as long as any single invocation of your listener method doesn't take much time. The GUI freezes while your handler is running.

Answer (score 1):

You should run separate threads for your events if you want to prevent UI blocking.

If you want to use a single thread for events then you can create the thread and you can pass commands to your event thread using a queue where you store your events.

But you should open async threads for your events if possible and you should make sure you refresh the UI whenever needed.